# In Java design is composition not used much anymore?

Tags: java, inheritance, aggregation, composition

A Java developer (with lots of experience in sophisticated, high-performance environments) very recently commented that **"composition is not used much anymore."** I was surprised by this comment. Is this true?

On the one hand, other answers on this forum indicate that difference between composition and aggregation can be ambiguous (can the whole exist without the part; does the part exist throughout the life of the containing object?). But perhaps in all of these cases the question stands--how to add behavior to an existing class or class hierarchy.

The context of his comment was a discussion of possible alternatives to inheritance. If this developer is correct, what has replaced composition in working practice? Mix-ins through added interfaces?

Any perspectives are welcome!

Comment: Do you have classes with fields? Yes? There you go.

Comment: No, absolute rubbish. In fact Joshua Bloch quite clearly says "Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance".

Comment: You (and J.Bloch) are right as long as you don't care much about ultimate performance and memory footprint.

However in performance-critical software it is better sometimes to use inheritance in order to avoid penalty of walking through the extra reference.

A typical example is Java 7 ConcurrentHashMap.Segment class that extends ReentrantLock to save some memory and improve performance. For the similar reason Java 8 LongAdder, DoubleAccumulator etc. extend auxiliary Striped64 class instead of making a composition.

Answer (score 1):

If anything, it's probably used now more than ever thanks to dependency injection frameworks like Spring. The model that all of the Java developers I know use is to build classes that relate to one another in functionality more by interface and purpose and to use Spring to inject them according to a particular configuration (ex the ability to replace entire security frameworks just by changing a spring configuration file and adding a few new JAR files).

Comment: 1+ and don't forget Guice either. :)

Comment: Thanks very much, all, for your comments. I will note apangin's observation about performance. Mike T's comment about Spring is also very relevant. There may be contexts where composition is not used, but as several of you confirm my assumption that composition is certainly still used in mainstream contexts--and front and centre in Spring and other injection frameworks.